# React-Native Error: Tried to synchronously call function {withSpring} from a diffreent thread

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

there is small part of my code throwing error on some of devices with possible solutions:
a) If you want to synchronously execute, mark it as a Worklet
b) If you want to execute this method on JS thread, wrap it using runOnJS.

Error appear only on certain devices.

```
    const movingStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        'worklet';
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: withSpring(translateX.value, {
                        damping: 10,
                        restSpeedThreshold: 5,
                    }),
                },
            ],
        };
    });


    return (
        <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={swipeGestureHandler}>
            <Animated.View style={[movingStyle, styles.profilecontainer]}>
                <ImageBackground> ... </ImageBackground>
            </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    );
```

I tried to wrap it into runOnJS or use Worklet, but none of them worked for me.

I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

**I found this solution useLegacyImplementation worked for me.**

```
 <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation={true}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={AppScreenName.home}
        component={HomeViewController}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```